# Weak notion of equivalence in a category

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, I was thinking about a subcategory $\mathcal{S}$ formed by throwing away all the morphisms having no left inverse(or right inverse). Then we denote, for each pair $X, Y \in \mathfrak{ob}(\mathcal{S})$, $X \leq Y$ if $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{S}}(X,Y)$ is not the empty class. Let's say $X \sim Y$ if $X \leq Y$ and $Y \leq X$. If we let $\mathcal{P}$ be a full subcategory of $\mathcal{S}$ consisting of each objects in the equivalance class, then we could define many order-(or set-)theoretic notions on $\mathcal{P}$.

My question is, what types of categories have this property: $X \sim Y$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as usual categorical sense?
If a category satisfy this condition, then we can translate all the theory of poset on that category, so this question is extremely meaningful to ask.

Such examples include the the category $\mathbf{Set}$(Cantor-Bernstein Theorem), the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a fixed field, etc.
The $\mathcal{P}$ in the first case gives quite complicated model and the second case gives the structure isomorphic to the natural numbers.

My aim is to consider filters on this kind of poset and build a class of ultrafilters each of which representing a point of the category $\mathcal{P}$, analogous to the Stone–Čech compactification of a topological space.
Although this procedure can be done with any category, I'm wondering the above question for the sake of computability of the points of the compactification of the category $\mathcal{P}$.

ps) Since I paused studying mathematics for a while and I don't have firm knowledge on the set theory dealing with classes, if there is any helpful material dealing with general foundation and construction of a set theory other than $ZFC$, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: EI-categories are a good source of examples.  Popular among homotopy theorists.

Comment: @Randall Thank you for your comments. And one more thing what I'm worrying about is that if the collection of object in the category doesn't form a set, then we need to define the partial order on each of subclasses which is in fact a set. Does such a definition makes sense? Or could we define a relation on a class as a class? Because I doesn' know well what can I do with classes and what I cannot, I'm just bravely defining all the things by my taste and that can lead me to a trap.

Comment: Yes, you are right to be careful of set-theoretic problems.  In my area, such constructions are only carried out in small categories, so the issue never arises.  (If I ever encounter a category that's too large, I take an appropriate skeleton and show that that avoids the problem.  Since they're equivalent, there's no loss of data.)

Comment: @Randall Yeah, I also considered skeleton and maybe some strict restrictions would be better for many purposes. Honestly, I have a bad habit to constructing things in a full generality, when the general theme may not have any advantage over somehow restrictive one. Though, I'm going to study general set theory for any sake in the future. Thank you for comments.

Comment: @Randall And I'll have to introduce a notion resembling skeleton, but each object from the equivalence classes defined above instead the isomorphism classes.